# Image on Homepage did not Show up

Tags: php, magento, magento2, product

I've a problem since 3 weeks with the product image. I've been searching for an answer, but ending with nothing.

The problem is only in the homepage (using the theme block), whereas in other pages the image is shown correctly.

The problem seems to be with the image url: the image is loaded without filename and extension, like this:
`http://example.com/pub/media/catalog/product/resized/300x300/cc38bbb6f31fe236840f8efa61c92297/`
The file name doesnt load perfectly.  To be more specific, this is the screenshot from my homepage right now  [link](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2788572/e29304ad981133b16d4abd6d486c6822) .

I'm using magento 2.1.5, I've tried `php bin/magento catalog:images:resize` , `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` and deploying. But still doesnt solve my problem. 
Any clue?

Comment: dunno if it can help, but have you correctly set the view.xml file inside the /etc folder, with size images, in your theme? have you  tried applying another theme if the same thing happens?

Comment: @sissy hi thanks for trying. i dont have file view.xml in my directories (app/etc). is that the right directories?

Comment: nope. It has to be put inside <magento_root_dir>/app/design/frontend/YourVendor/yourTheme/etc/view.xml. Check it here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html#fedg_create_theme_how-to-images

Comment: @sissy yep, everything was set. And now i know the problem is with my theme, because when i tried with another theme everything was fine. Do you know what cause this problem in my theme?

Comment: well we have at least narrowed the problem. Can you edit your question with the code you are using to show the image in the home page? Maybe someone can give better help.